# How to read a file from nth byte to a string - C#

Tags: c#, file-io

I need to read a file from 27th byte to a string in C#.

Thanks,
siva.

Comment: So you want to read a file into a string, skipping the first 26 bytes?

Comment: Bytes aren't text.  You need to use an encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Encoding encoding = Encoding.ASCII; //? (Encoding.Default)
using (var f = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open))
{
    f.Position = 27;
    var yourString = new StreamReader(f,encoding).ReadToEnd();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using(var fs = new FileStream("foo.txt")
{
    var bytes = new byte[fs.Length - 27];
    fs.Position = 27;
    fs.Read(bytes, 27, fs.Length - 27);
    var value = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be `fs.Position = 26`?

Comment: @sixlettervariables Sounds right

Answer (score 1):

```
byte[] allBytes = File.GetAllBytes(path);
byte[] bytes = allBytes.Skip(27).ToArray();

// Convert bytes to string
var encoding = ...
string result = encoding.GetString(bytes);
```

Note that you need to choose the right encoding.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you're looking for the hexadecimal representation of the bytes, you'll need to read the file into a byte array, then pass the bytes you're interested in to BitConverter.GetString(byte[] bytes);